# Filtering Data Frame by using a Dynamic Data Frame

Tags: r

I need to filter or subset a data frame (df1) that has 13 static columns variables by another data frame (df2) that contains the sames columns names as df1 but not the same number of columns. Df2 is user generated and contains the columns that the user wants to filter df1 by.So df2 may contain only one column name or 8 columns.

df1

```
V1     V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
Chevy  V8  4D  AT  PS  NAV
Chevy  V8  2D  MT  MS  NONAV
```

df2

```
V3   V4  V6
4D   AT  NAV
```

Results

```
V1     V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
Chevy  V8  4D  AT  PS  NAV
```

How can I do this in R? Subsetting does not seem like a good option since the column names in df2 are dynamic and will always different. So using df2$V3 is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can do a `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df2, df1) %>%
        select_(.dots = names(df1))
#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5  V6
#1 Chevy V8 4D AT PS NAV
```

---

Or using `merge` from `base R`

```
 merge(df1, df2, all.y= TRUE)[names(df1)]
 #    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5  V6
 #1 Chevy V8 4D AT PS NAV
```

Answer (score 0):

This exactly the job for `semi_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
semi_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I can only use base R. I do not have the dplyr package nor can I install it. Can I use sqldf?

Comment: In that case modification of akrun's answer with `merge` will work:
`merge(df1, df2)[, names(df1), drop = FALSE]`